# Constraining the response scale of a smooth function in an mgcv GAM

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

tl/dr: I have a GAM of several predictor variables and smooth functions. I need to constrain one of these smooth functions such that the response of this function is between 0 and 1.

I have a GAM in which I am attempting to predict catch (of fish; data is from a series of scientific surveys) as a function of several predictor variables with NegBinom distributed error.

The equation looks like this:

```
l(catch) ~ NB(year + survey + s(length, by=survey) + s(lon, lat)
```

Each term is attempting to control for various sources of variance in the catch response:

- `year` should control for annual fluctuations in population
- `survey` controls for differences in the catch 'efficiency' of different surveys. Basically the rate of catch per unit of effort by the survey
- `s(lon, lat)` is a spatial field which controls for the average spatial distribution of the stock

This leaves `s(length, by=survey)`, which is the function in need of constraint. The intent of this parameter is to control for the 'size-selectivity' of each survey. Basically each gear-type and sampling protocol has variable effectiveness at catching fish at different lengths. Here's an example of a selectivity curve:

[image]

The X axis shows 'AGE' but the salient characteristic here is length. What this functions tells us is that this  hypothetical survey reaches peak catch-efficiency at ~11 years of age. Prior to that, as a consequence of the size of the target fish, the gear is less effective.

Selectivity must always be constrained between 0 and 1, as it is a proportional response. Unfortunately, when I fit my GAM, the curve responses range from 0-40. It appears to be soaking up the variance from elsewhere in the model, most likely from the `year` and `survey` parameters, with which is it confounded.

Wondering if there is a way that I can impose additional penalization on the smooth function such that its response values are constrained.

Comment: Why should the effect of length *on catch* be constrained to lie between 0 and 1 when it is the relationship of length (age) *on selectivity* that should be constrained? Your model is allowing the former effect to vary by survey but it shouldn't be constrained to lie between 0 and 1 as the smooth `s(length, by = survey)` is not modelling a selectivity function as selectivity isn't the response.

Comment: But given that this is fitted in logistic space, each of the model elements has a multiplicative effect on the catch response. Essentially I'm trying to recreate the equation:
```
Catch = N * q * s
```

In this case, the `year` effect takes the place of N, the `survey` effect takes the place of q, and the `s(length)` function takes the place of s. The unit of response *is* catch, but  does that necessarily mean that the output units of each individual model component must be as well, or simply that their *final product* must be in units of catch?